# I am using fgets() to read in a line in PHP. But i am getting a wierd result?

Tags: php, fgets

```
$size = intval(trim(fgets($fp,4)));
$triangle = range(1,$size);
for($j=0;$j<$size;$j=$j+1)
    $triangle[$j] = split(" ",trim(fgets($fp,400)));
```

This code reads in the number of lines to read, then reads them one by one. Issue is, when first input line ends in space, it reads that space as a new line.

Comment: Well you are specifying for `fgets` to only read 3 bytes.. [php.net/fgets](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)

Answer (score 1):

you can read full file content by file_get_contents.

```
<?php
$content= file_get_contents('myfile.txt');
echo $content;
?>
```